# Logging all debug info for one particular app?

Tags: django, logging

I setup logging and it's working great. What I want to do now is log all debug info for one particular app called 'my app' in addition to the other logs and am not sure how to achieve this.

Working set up as it is now:

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    #
    'formatters': {
        'default': {
            'format': '\n%(levelname)s - %(asctime)s\n%(message)s\n'
        },
    },
    #
    'handlers': {
        #
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler',
            'include_html': True,
        },
        #
        'debug_log': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
            'filename': '/var/log/django/debug.log',
            'maxBytes': 1024*1024*5, 
            'backupCount': 5,
            'formatter': 'default',
        },
        #
        'error_log': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'class': 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
            'filename': '/var/log/django/error.log',
            'maxBytes': 1024*1024*5,
            'backupCount': 5,
            'formatter': 'default',
        },
    },
    #
    'loggers': {
        '': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins', 'error_log',],
            'level': 'INFO',
            'propagate': True,
        },
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['debug_log',],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    }
}
```

I'd like to set up DEBUG logging that captures everything for the one particular app. I add the following **handler** to LOGGING:

```
        'app_log': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
            'filename': '/var/log/django/app.log',
            'maxBytes': 1024*1024*5,
            'backupCount': 5,
            'formatter': 'default',
        },
```

And the following **logger**:

```
    'my_app': {
        'handlers': ['app_log',],
        'level': 'DEBUG',
        'propagate': True,
    },
```

Add the following to my_app.views:

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

And here's where I'm not sure what I need to do next. I can add something like the following to a certain view

```
    ...
    if blahblahblah:
        logger.debug('My Message Here')
    ...
```

and things work great. However, what I really want is all debug info for the entire app, not just 'My Message Here'. I want all the query info etc... ie: same info as the standard debug logging but just for that one app.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: yes I did. Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: Glad to have been of help. All the best with your project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't explicitly enabled the [SQL query logging](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/logging/#django-db-backends) but I am uncertain if it can be enabled in app scope. AFAIK it can only be enabled or disabled for the entire project.

If you want to do this at the app level, or view level you can try this:

```
from django.db import connection
logger.debug(connection.queries)
```

Place this code at the end of each view where you want to see the sql logs.